# directive attribute value is not passing

Tags: angularjs

hey everyone i am calling directive and passing hardcode to the directive but it is not passing. i could not what's the issue in my code. 
code:

i am calling directive something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="EmployeeController">
    <off-balance user-key="18" collapse-hide="true"></off-balance>
</div>
```

directive code:

```
App.directive('offBalance', ['OffService', 'toaster', OffBalance]);

function OffBalance(OffService, toaster, ) {
    var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/modules/sometemplate.html',
            scope: {
                userKey: '=',
                collapsehide: '=?',
            },
            scope: true 

        }
    }

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attr) {

        scope.$watch('userKey', function (newVal) {
            alert("userKey" + newVal);

        });

        scope.$watch('collapsehide', function (newVal) {
            alert("collapsehide" + newVal);
        });
    }
}
```

userkey and collapsehide both are undefined. please help me to fixed this issue

Answer (score 3):

Please find working plunker below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/y75jQhDCWlEBb2pDNKEs?p=preview

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);

App.directive('offBalance', [OffBalance]);

function OffBalance() {
    var directive = {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        userKey: '=',
        collapseHide: '=?'
    }
}
return directive;
}


function link(scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch('userKey', function(newVal) {
    alert("userKey" + newVal);
});
console.log(scope);
scope.$watch('collapseHide', function(collapseHide) {
    alert("collapsehide" + collapseHide);
});
}
```

Below are the points to be noted:

1. `scope` is two times in your directive.
2. collapsehide should be collapseHide as angular strict towards naming of attribute and directive.
3. `return directive` should be inside `function OffBalance()`

Comment: is there any way we can use both scope??

Comment: No, you can't. Both scope has their own meaning. when we write `scope: true` directive gets new scope and when we write `scope: {}`, directive gets new isolated scope.

Answer (score 1):

remove `scope: true` and replace `collapsehide: '=?'` by `collapseHide: '=?'` idem in your watcher